# Bad state: Stream has already been listened to. When using http.Response.fromStream()

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to send audio file to my flask server and get back a prediction string.
However, I'm getting the following error

```
 Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
```

My Code:

```
  var uri = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict');
  var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  //request.fields['audio'] = "audio";

  var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('audio', (await 
  rootBundle.load("assets/audioFile.aac")).buffer.asUint8List( ), filename: 
  'audioFile.aac');

  request.files.add(multipartFile);
  request.headers["Content-Type"] = 'multipart/form-data';
  var streamedResponse = await request.send();
  var x =  await streamedResponse.stream.toBytes();
  var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
  Map<String, dynamic> result = jsonDecode(response.body);
  predic = "${result['emotion']}";

  return predic;
```

I read that I must use streamController.broadcast or BehaviorSubject. But I'm not using any controllers in my code.